# Android Studio loading device button is disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova

My Android Studio loading device button is disabled for my cordova project but it is perfectly working for other project.

Things I have tried:

1. Making sure my SDK path is correct
2. Running Android Studio as administrator

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC8Q1.jpg)

Can anyone tell me why it is happening.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Adding screenshots will be more helpful. If you can add some pics of your situation or icon you're not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is due to version of gradle.I have to change the gradle version.
go to file -> Project Structure -> Gradle Version and change the gradle version.