# Android Studio 'Loading Devices' unable to active

Tags: android-studio, adb

I am facing a problem, My android studio application. Loading Devices is disabling. I tried many ways to resolve that. but nothing didn't work.

-Create a New Project, Error didn't resolve.

-Restart the application even system also.

-Followed Previous posts :

[Android Studio loading device button is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66507050/android-studio-loading-device-button-is-disabled)

[Android studio virtual device not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298046/android-studio-virtual-device-not-loading)

Nothing Worked!!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Restart** the PC and then **don't** open Android Studio directly , but **run it as Administrator** , this can be some **permission issue** , you can also try **File->Invalidate Cache & Restart** !

Comment: Yes, I tried, I saw this solution from another post. But it didn't work. I also reinstall my device drivers as well also do updates.

Comment: can you try this ? Go to File->Invalidate Cache and Restart , ping me after trying this !

Comment: @NisargJani invalidate cache and restart did the trick

Comment: That's Great ! Just do one thing add your answer here and mark it as correct , it will be helpful for others !

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill adb with `adb kill-server` in the terminal tab **inside** Android Studio. It will be restarted automatically. If this does not help try `adb devices` in the terminal to see if the device is at least listed in the terminal. If you are under Linux you also need [special permissions](http://www.janosgyerik.com/adding-udev-rules-for-usb-debugging-android-devices/) to access USB.

Also you have to enable on the phone USB debugging and confirm the access from the PC in case you have not yet done so.

Comment: Didn't work!

"D:\Under_Dev\MyApplication3>adb kill-server
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
"

Comment: You have to use the internal terminal inside Android Studio.

Comment: Just restarting `adb` should be sufficient to reset the program, restarting the computer is the last option to reset the PC in an initial state, but will not reveal the actual issue.

Comment: there can be some issues with processes inside windows, that's why I suggested restart !